# How make fonts render in PhpStorm2017.1 good

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2016.3 on Ubuntu fonts in IDE rendering perfectly, but in new version 2017.1 it's now again look bad.

How do I make the fonts look good again?

**Solution for me:**
I copied jre folder from old PhpStorm in external directory and configure new version of Ide with this jre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (from the original question):

> ...copied jre folder from old PhpStorm in external directory and configured new version of the IDE with this jre.

Comment: Worked for me. Used the jre from the previous version